# Parse error: parse error, expecting `'{'' in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get this error on Code igniter:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `'{'' in www\site\system\application\controllers\criacao-de-sites-bh.php on line 4

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//require_once('./system/application/libraries/MY_FrontController.php');

class Criacao-de-sites-bh extends Controller {

function criacao-de-sites-bh()
{
    parent::Controller();

    $this->_data['controle'] = "criacao-de-sites-bh";
```

Does anyone please know what to do to fix it? I think its an error due to the hyphen (-).

Thank you!

Comment: *"I think its an error due to the hyphen (-)."* - So, change them to underscores and try it again.

Comment: Dont use '-' in your function names.

Comment: Hello, Fred.I need to use hyphen, due to SEO needs.

Comment: SEO has nothing to do with how PHP code is structured. PHP cannot accept hyphens there. You _must_ use underscores.

Comment: @Hans no you don't... just use proper routes

Comment: But you -- cant -- use hyphons, so change your SEO needs :P

Comment: What next, you going to put meta data tags in your code?

Comment: [Here is the relevant documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) for setting up routes in CodeIgniter. Classes and methods don't have to be directly mapped 1:1 with HTTP requests.

Comment: If it's a problem with your SEO urls redirect to the correct one using htaccess

Comment: Thank you all.
I solved it with Michael's solution: routes!
@MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 4):

A classname in PHP is limited [to the alphanumerics and underscores](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The class name can be any valid label, provided it is not a PHP reserved word. A valid class name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: ^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$.

Your usage of `-` as a separator is not valid for a class name, and PHP fails to parse the name.

The naming scheme should be coherent with the rest of your application, either underscores (`Criacao_De_Sites_Bh` or `CriacaoDeSitesBh`).

Comment: Thank you. Solved with Michael's solution: routes!